# RxJS Google Maps Markers

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to retrieve only new `"Google Map" Markers` from DataBase by utilizing `RxJS observables` and `jQuery $.ajax`

I'm receiving an array of markers every 5 seconds. 
When the data inside the array has been changed, i.e new markers appended, I need to filter out only new markers.

```
var oldArray = [["ObjA",3455,643523,2],["ObjB",5346,2134,1],["ObjC",5341,7135,0]];
var newArray = [["ObjA",3455,643523,2],["ObjD",2384,4791,3],["ObjB",5346,2134,1],["ObjC",5341,7135,0],["ObjF",2631,7228,4]];
```

So here from `newArray` I need to filter out `["ObjD",2384,4791,3]` and `["ObjF",2631,7228,4]`

I have no clue how it can be done, and can it be done at all by utilizing only RxJS.

I would really appreciate if someone could lead me in the right direction!

```
var observable = Rx.Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .flatMap(function() {
    return Rx.Observable
      .from($.ajax({url: "https://somedomain.com/json"}).promise())
  })
  .filter(x => !!x === true)
  .distinctUntilChanged();


observable.subscribe((response) => {
      var newMarker = $.parseJSON(response.data);                    
});
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck?

Comment: @paulpdaniels, Thanks for Your reply. I really appreciate it. I've updated my question with the code snippet. I've been trying to complete that task in many different ways but with no success. This is the code from my last try. Please don't judge me strictly 'cause I'm really new to RxJS and trying to do my best to get it quickly and  in the proper way.
Thanks again!

Comment: So the part that you are stuck at is what to do once you have the data back from the server?

Comment: @paulpdaniels, not really. I'm receiving an array of markers every 5 seconds. The task I'm trying to solve is when the data inside the array has been changed, i.e new markers appended for example, i need to filter out only new markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working on arrays, you don't need RxJS, you can use the new array operators in ES6:

```
onlyNewArray = 
    newArray
        .filter(newItem => 
            !oldArray.some(oldItem => oldItem[0] === newItem[0]));
```

`some()` will go through the items in the array one by one and if any fulfill the criteria it will return true. Here we check if each of the items in `newArray` is present in the old, and if they are don't include them in `onlyNewArray`

---

**Update**

This will check if all items in `oldItem` are equal to the corresponding item in `newItem`:

```
onlyNewArray = 
    newArray
        .filter(newItem => 
            !oldArray.some(oldItem => 
                oldItem.every((prop, index) =>
                    prop === newItem[index])));
```

---

**Update 2**

To only check a consecutive part of the array, you can slice it first:

```
onlyNewArray = 
    newArray
        .filter(newItem => 
            !oldArray.some(oldItem => 
                oldItem
                    .slice(0,3)
                    .every((prop, index) =>
                        prop === newItem[index])));
```

Alternatively, you can provide an index to skip and then use a simple `if/else` clause:

```
let dontCheck = 1;

onlyNewArray = 
    newArray
        .filter(newItem => 
            !oldArray.some(oldItem => 
                oldItem.every((prop, index) => {
                    if(index == dontCheck){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        prop === newItem[index]
                    }
                })));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really works as expected. 
Tell me please, is it possible to filter by all elements in array? Here we're filtering by first one, but for example if I need to compare all elements in the array, or by specific elements only?

Sorry if I'm asking too much.  Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Thank You so much Jon!
Could You please advise also on how to filter by specific array elements.
["ObjA",3455,643523,2]
For example I need to filter by 0,1,2 but element 3 to be skipped and not taken into account.? Thank You!
Or by 0,2,3 and skip 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer with two possibilities. I'd recommend reading up on the operators in Mozilla's docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thank You! You're my savior!